# rails How to migration find_all_by_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find-all-references

Hi I migrate an app from Rails 2 to Rails 7.04.

I don't see how to rewrite :

```
self.accepted_roles.find_all_by_name(role_name).any? { |role| role.users }

users = self.accepted_roles.find_all_by_name(role_name).collect { |role| role.users }

users.flatten.uniq if users
```

I think `self.roles.where("name="role_name).find_each` but `.any?` and `.collect`

I don't find Rails 2 documentation.
Help is welcome

Comment: I would seriously consider if you want to do a re-write. Rails 1 is just so different from later versions and updating 6 major versions is going to be a very long and painful upgrade path. Unless its a big application it might take you significantly longer then a re-write.

Comment: `User.where(id: self.accepted_roles.joins(:users).where(name: role_name).select(User.arel_table[:id]).distinct)` should work. That being said I agree with @max Rails 2 -> Rails 7 is a massive jump and accordingly should be done incrementally which, if done correctly, will take a very long time. A rewrite and data migration is likely a more cleaner and more efficient path.

Comment: Yes it is a massive jump. In begining, i want to jump to Rails 3 but it is not possible on Rehl 8. And it is very very difficult to have an OS version-Ruby -rails stable configuration.  is "any?" = "distinct"  ?? i don't know arel_table?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `.where()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Not clear. I use .where() but how to translate . any? and .collect    ?

Comment: For example: Book.where(category: "Ruby", author: "Jesus Castello")
This returns books that match both category & author. If there are no matches it will return nill.

Comment: You translate Book.find_all_by_category_and_author(ruby,author) but how to translate Book.find_all_by_category_and_author(ruby,author).any? How to translate Book.find_all_by_category_and_author(ruby,author).collect  Any? and collect not important???

Comment: If with ".any?" you want to find if there is any instance with these attributes then i have already answered. Use .where() which will return nill if there are no matches.

Comment: So Book.find_all_by_category_and_author(ruby,author) or Book.find_all_by_category_and_author(ruby,author).any? is the same request. And with ".collect" ?

Comment: If with .collect you want to store the instances just write:
variable = Tablename.Where(...)
and the results will be stored in your variable.

Comment: Sidenote: `where()` will never return `nil` it will always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. This object can have no members but it will never be `nil`